# Program Reading Last Line of File Twice

Tags: c, filereader

I am writing a program that reads a `.txt` file line by line. I have been able to do this so far, but the last line of the file is read twice. I can't seem to figure out why. Thank you for your help in advance! Here is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINELENGTH 200

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* textFile;
    char buffer[MAX_LINELENGTH];
    char strName[40];
    int numCharsTot;
    int numWordsInMesg;
    int numCharsInMesg;

    textFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(textFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while(!feof(textFile))
    {
        fgets(buffer, MAX_LINELENGTH, textFile); //Gets a line from file
        //printf("Got Line: %s\n", buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'while(!feof(textFile))' - I knew it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(!feof(textFile))
```

is wrong, you end up "eating" the end of file. You should do

```
while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LINELENGTH, textFile))
{
    // process the line
}
```

Related: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

`eof` file indicator set after read the last line.

```
while(!feof(textFile))
{
    fgets(buffer, MAX_LINELENGTH, textFile); //Gets a line from file
```

Please correct above code snippet as follows:

```
while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LINELENGTH, textFile))
{
```